# JPA composite key (FKs + date) set date to auto_increment

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I am working on a Java play project and trying to create a time tracker for users on projects. I have the following class for tracking time:

```java
@Entity(name = "trackings")
public class Tracking extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    public TrackingPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("user")
    @JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
    public User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("project")
    @JoinColumn(name="project", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Project project;

    @Required
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public ETrackingDuration duration;

    @Embeddable
    public class TrackingPK implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private User user;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Project project;

        @Column(name="date", columnDefinition="DATE NOT NULL")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date date;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, JPA keeps making date as an `auto_increment` and I have no idea why.

Here are my logs:

```
09:14:16,939 ERROR ~ HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table trackings (date datetime not null auto_increment, project_id bigint not null, user_id bigint not null, id bigint not null, duration varchar(255), primary key (date, project_id, user_id, id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
09:14:16,939 ERROR ~ Incorrect column specifier for column 'date'
09:14:16,941 ERROR ~ HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table trackings add index FK_fjady3y2u9ej76atpce4djsu5 (project_id), add constraint FK_fjady3y2u9ej76atpce4djsu5 foreign key (project_id) references projects (id)
09:14:16,941 ERROR ~ Table 'trackings' doesn't exist
09:14:16,944 ERROR ~ HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table trackings add index FK_rdi49oyr8mro9t6vjj5towo0b (user_id), add constraint FK_rdi49oyr8mro9t6vjj5towo0b foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
```

Foreign keys are correct but not `date`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the mapping that I can see:

- You need `@MapsId("user")` and `@MapsId("project")` on `Tracking.user` and `Tracking.project`, respectively
- The `@Column` annotations on `TrackingPK.user` and `TrackingPK.project` are redundant with `@MapsId` in place (you may actually run into problems if you define the same column twice in JPA, without declaring it `insertable=false, updatable=false` in one of the definitions)
- JPA allows `java.util.Date` *as long as the temporal type is set to `TemporalType.DATE`* (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm; your JPA provider might allow it, though, but you would need to check)

As regards the schema definition problem, if all else fails, try using `columnDefinition="date not null"` to override the default SQL for that column.

EDIT It turns out that `play.db.jpa.Model` defines an `@Id` column. Mixing `@Id` and `@EmbeddedId` is what causes the problem. You'll want to extend from `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` instead.

Comment: I have updated my question with your advices.
Still, date is created as an `auto_increment`

Comment: Which JPA provider?

Comment: Nevermind, I can see from the logs it's Hibernate. Are you sure you have configured the correct dialect in `persistence.xml` (e.g. `<property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>`)?

Comment: Also, where is the extra `id` column coming from? Would you happen to have an `@Id` declared in the `Model` class? Mixing `@Id` and `@EmbeddedId` is not allowed. I'd try dropping the inheritance  `Tracking -> Model` to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: You'll want to extend from `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` rather than `play.db.jpa.Model` in this version of Play. It is the `play.db.jpa.Model` that adds the `id` field

Comment: That's it. `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` solved my problem. Thank you